# Can I see how many gems I bid when I won an auction?

Tags: steam, steam-holiday-auction

I won an auction in the Steam Holiday Auction yesterday. I want to compare how much I bid with the current bid for the same item. Is there some place I can see how many gems I paid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The email Steam sent you informing you that you won the auction says the price you bid.

Comment: Thank you. No wonder I won. That was WAY too much...